# T-SQL aggregate over contiguous dates more efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a need to aggregate a sum over contiguous dates.  I've seen solutions to similar problems that will return the start and end dates, but don't have a need to aggregate the data between those ranges.  It's further complicated by the extremely large amounts of data involved, to the point that a simple self join takes an impractical amount of time (especially since the start and end date fields are unindexed)

I have a solution involving cursors, but I've generally been led to believe that cursors can always be more efficiently replaced with joins that will execute faster, but so far every solution I've tried with a query anywhere close to giving me the data I need takes an hour at least, and my cursor solutions takes about 10 seconds.  So I'm asking if there is a more efficient answer.

And the data includes both buy and sell transactions and each row of aggregated contiguous dates returned also needs to list the transaction ID of the last sell that occurred before the first buy of the contiguous set of buy transactions.

An example of the data:

```
+------------------+------------+------------+------------------+--------------------+
| TRANSACTION_TYPE | TRANS_ID   | StartDate  | EndDate          | Amount             |
+------------------+------------+------------+------------------+--------------------+
| sell             | 100        | 2/16/16    | 2/18/18          | $100.00            |
| sell             | 101        | 3/1/16     | 6/6/16           | $121.00            |
| buy              | 102        | 6/10/16    | 6/12/16          | $22.00             |
| buy              | 103        | 6/12/16    | 6/14/16          | $0.35              |
| buy              | 104        | 6/29/16    | 7/2/16           | $5.00              |
| sell             | 105        | 7/3/16     | 7/6/16           | $115.00            |
| buy              | 106        | 7/8/16     | 7/9/16           | $200.00            |
| sell             | 107        | 7/10/16    | 7/13/16          | $4.35              |
| sell             | 108        | 7/17/16    | 7/20/16          | $0.50              |
| buy              | 109        | 7/25/16    | 7/29/16          | $33.00             |
| buy              | 110        | 7/29/16    | 8/1/16           | $75.00             |
| buy              | 111        | 8/1/16     | 8/3/16           | $0.33              |
| sell             | 112        | 9/1/16     | 9/2/16           | $99.00             |
+------------------+------------+------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Should have results like the following:

```
+------------+------------+------------------+--------------------+
| Last_Sell  | StartDate  | EndDate          | Amount             |
+------------+------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 101        | 6/10/16    | 6/14/18          | $22.35             |
| 101        | 6/29/16    | 7/2/16           | $5.00              |
| 105        | 7/8/16     | 7/9/16           | $200.00            |
| 108        | 7/25/16    | 8/3/16           | $108.33            |
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Right now I use queries to split the data into buys and sells, and just walk through the buy data, aggregating as I go, inserting into the return table every time I find a break in the dates, and I step through the sell table until I reach the last sell before the start date of the set of buys.

Walking linearly through cursors gives me a computational time of n.  Even though cursors are orders of magnitude less efficient, it's still calculating in n, while I suspect the joins I would need to do would give me at least n log n.  With the ridiculous amount of data I'm working with, the inefficiencies of cursors get swamped if it goes beyond linear time.

Comment: can you explain the logic? the question has no reference to it.

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that the transaction id increases along with the dates, then you can get the last sales date using a cumulative max.  Then, the adjacency can be found by using similar logic, but with a lag first:

```
with cte as (
      select t.*,
             sum(case when transaction_type = 'sell' then trans_id end) over
                 (order by trans_id) as last_sell,
             lag(enddate) over (partition by transaction_type order by trans_id) as prev_enddate
      from t
     )
select last_sell, min(startdate) as startdate, max(enddate) as enddate,
       sum(amount) as amount
from (select cte.*,
             sum(case when startdate = dateadd(day, 1, prev_enddate) then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by last_sell order by trans_id) as grp
      from cte 
      where transaction_type = 'buy'
     ) x
group by last_sell, grp;
```